# Does webhdfs support high availability when failover happens

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

iam using hadoop 2.7.1 on centos 7

when high availability  is included with hadoop cluster

and active name node fails ,it becomes stand by

but webhdfs doesn't support high availability ?isn't it

what should be the alternative to send get and put request to other active name

node with the failure of master name node

Comment: is there any download for httpfs-3.0.0-alpha2.tar.gz i haven't found any one yet

Comment: `httpfs` is included in the hadoop binary distribution itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, WebHDFS is not High Availability aware. This issue is still open. Refer [HDFS-6371](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6371)

Instead, you can opt for [HttpFs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/). It is inteoperable with the webhdfs REST API and HA aware.

Or, write your custom implementation to redirect requests to the Active Namenode.

Comment: even though we redirect our  requests to  currently active name node(which becomes active after main name node failure) that will not success when  our request is put , because the data node will redirect this  request to base main  name node  which currently fails ,isn't this true

Comment: can you suggest some useful links and videos for httpfs handling ,if there are any

Comment: when i'am issuing the following command curl -i -L "http://192.168.4.128:50070/webhdfs/v1/aloosh                                                                                                                     /a1.tbl/?user.name=root&op=OPEN"
on putty terminal i get no response and after some time i get empty reply from server message  even though issuing this url from a browser works fine any idea?

Comment: No, the datanodes are configured with the information of both the namenodes and are designed to send block reports to both the namenodes. It is not the case for client requests, webhdfs do not handle it. Thus a suitable alternative, which is aware of HDFS HA, like HttpFs is required. As for the tutorial, HttpFs and WebHDFS work similarly. Use [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/ServerSetup.html) for setup and [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/UsingHttpTools.html) for getting started.

Answer (score 1):

Webhdfs server runs in the same process as NameNode. So you need to run webhdfs compatible proxy server, that would get rid of NN failover:

1. [HttpFs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html) - as part of Hadoop
2. [Apache Knox](https://knox.apache.org/)- as part of HDP distribution.

They both webhdfs compatible, so you don't need to change any REST API.